# Why do we use pthread_exit() when we can use return?

Tags: c, unix

In the following program `return p` gives the same output as `pthread_exit(p)`. Then why to use `pthread_exit()`?

```
void *foo(void *p){
    *((int *)p) += 1;
    pthread_exit(p);

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;
    int i=9;
    int *j;
    pthread_create(&t,NULL, foo, &i);
    pthread_join(t,(void**)&j);
    printf("%d\n",*j);
}
```

Comment: The value is available to the thread who joins if joinable, any handlers registered using `pthread_cleanup_push` are popped etc. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html

Comment: Another reason: suppose you start a thread. That thread calls one of your functions, which calls another function, but the function fails as a result of an unrecoverable error. Rather than returning from that function and continuing execution, checking the return value for an error condition that will just result in the thread exiting anyway, you could instead call `pthread_exit()` from that function and save yourself the trouble. It's not much different from a single-threaded program calling `exit()` for the same reason, save for the fact that you need to pass the return-value pointer around.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pthread_exit()` is for threads what `exit()` is for the main program.

Can you always terminate the main program using `return`?
I guess not. This is why `exit()` and `pthread_exit()` exist.

Returning from the main function of the thread performs an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`. The function is called no matter how you terminate your thread. It is responsible for thread's cleanup.

But if function `foo()` calls function `bar()` and `bar()` decides it must terminate the thread, it's more convenient to call `pthread_exit()` than to return from `bar()` and check the return value in `foo()`. The annoyance with `return` grows when the number of calls in the chain grows.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between these two is important if you use clean up handlers installed via `pthread_cleanup_push`

From the `pthread_cleanup_push` manpages it says:

> 1. When a thread is canceled, all of the stacked clean-up handlers are popped and executed in the reverse of the order in which they were pushed onto the stack.
> 2. When a thread terminates by calling pthread_exit(3), all clean-up handlers are executed as described in the preceding point.  (**Clean-up handlers are not called if the thread terminates by performing a return from the thread start function.**)

So if you installed clean up handlers they will not be called if you use return but they will be called if you use `pthread_exit`.

Comment: Curiously, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ says: `Regardless of the method of thread termination, any cancellation cleanup handlers that have been pushed and not yet popped are executed, and the destructors for any existing thread-specific data are executed.`, making me wonder if this is unfortunate wording, or Linux diverges from POSIX here. Does anyone know?